# C function signature with asterisk

Tags: c

I have been attempting C recently and have been reading C source code,
however I came across this perculiar method signature with a * beside its name, 
can someone explain this to me please

```
int *bubble_sort(int *numbers, int count, compare_cb cmp)
```

edit: I am referring to the * infront of bubble_sort

Comment: The * is used with `pointers` when not used to denote multiplication.

Comment: can you kindly explain with examples?

Comment: If you are learning C, you need to look for a good tutorial or textbook to get acquainted with the fundamentals. And no, I will not recommend any - that's where Google comes in.

Comment: It means the function returns a pointer to an `int`.  You will need to find a good book to learn from.  The subject of pointers is too big to be covered in an answer on SO.

Comment: there we go, jonathan gave the answer, thank you!

Comment: It means that for some peculiar reason, this function returns a pointer.  The standard `qsort()` function, for example, doesn't return any value.  Most likely, it simply returns the value passed as `numbers`.  But there's no knowing what or why without looking at the source code.

Comment: @laycat: It might have been more apparent to you if the prototype had been written: `int* bubble_sort(int* numbers, int count, compare_cb cmp);`.  There are differing opinions on which form is 'better' similar to the arguments over brace placement.

Comment: thank you Jonathan, I am currently very confused as I am currently reading using functions as callback and was worried that the * could be a pointer to the code. I would have thought that "int* bubblesort()" would represent the bubblesort method returning a pointer to an integer

Comment: whitespace is not significant in C

Comment: C is a free-format language.  There are very few places where spaces are significant in C (`#define macro(x, y)` is one of the few).  So, the spacing in `int * bubblesort(…)` is immaterial.

Comment: Guys, what about this? why would a method return a pointer to void?

Comment: void *Object_move(void *self, Direction direction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '*', used in this way, indicates that the 'bubble_sort()' function returns an address of (in other words, 'a pointer to) an integer, rather than an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk has nothing to do with the function signature, it's just C's way of declaring pointers. The asterisk belongs to the type on the left, i.e. the return type for the function is `int *`, which is read out as "pointer to integer". The first argument has the exact same type, pointer to integer. You use this syntax everywhere in C, not just with function declarations.

Comment: Isn't it at least part of the function signature? The signature is the whole prototype, right?

Comment: No, the return type is not part of the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

This concept is of pointers.
To know more about pointers see this link : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm

```
int *bubble_sort(int *numbers, int count, compare_cb cmp)

int *bubble_sort means that you are going to return the address of the integer,
and int *numbers means that you are getting the address of the variable as argument.
```

Answer (score 0):

int a() is a function returning an int.
int * a() is a function returning a pointer to an int.

in your case the function returns a pointer to an integer.
guessing from the function name it is returning the sorted array.

an array in C is notated as a pointer to the first element:

```
int a[5];
int *b=a;
a and b are the same
```

However I guess you still have to do some more research on pointers which is not as complicated.
Perhaps this links might help: [Pointer Primer](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm)

Comment: "a and b are the same" --> "&a[0] and b currently both point to the same element"